# Create an advanced List With CheckBox and "More" Button For Android

Tags: java, android, list, checkbox

First, sorry for my bad English, i'm a French Student. And i'm also a beginner (in?) on Android Development.

I'm actually working on an Android Project with advanced LDAP synchronisations with Android Contact. 
I'm stuck on a view, i want a specific list.

This is my construction of list : 

-> Parent "City" 
     ---> Child "Department"
!
Each City contain a specific number of department.

I would like to add the More Button on the "City" (Parent) to expand and let us see the "Department" (Child) who are actually some checkbox. 
I don't know how it's called, in French and in English ...

I need some help here, i only found a document on this : [Android: Optionsmenu 'More-list' with icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657682/android-optionsmenu-more-list-with-icons) but i don't understand how to make it in code. I need some sample to be more efficient.

EDIT : I forget to say all my data are extract from a JSON, so i don't know how many item i have (Parents & Childs).
So i need a programaticaly response.

I file with this post a scan of what i want, i hope that help you to understand what i need.

Thank you for help and response =)

Cordially,

Thomas
[image: Basic Example Schema]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for Expandable List
[ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)
[ExpandableListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html)

Comment: Thank you, i will try it tomorrow. I edit the question to be more precise.